# Zyxel router DNS and speed issue

Tags: wireless-networking, dns, wireless-router, connection, speed

I have a problem with my connection. We switched to a new ISP few weeks ago to a faster DSL connection. Everything was great, speed was as expected. Now from yesterdays evening I'm getting some connection drops when only Skype and Messenger work and browser tells me that DNS couldn't be reached. I've done some research but I don't know which solution is right for me. So, I decided to ask here. Now I didn't had that problem since yesterday but my father on his laptop was constantly disconnected every day for at least once. He had to disconnect and then connect again. Now I'm getting this problem too with, also slow speeds. Very unstable. I logged into admin and some particular line caught my eye.
Connection Rate: 11 Mbps. When I click on my laptop connection details this line is always changing to 144, 24 and so on. I don't know if it helps you to help me but it's always changing, and I don't know why.

I tried changing DNS from dynamic to provided by ISP. I tried also `Static` with Googles DNS (I read it somewhere). I tried switching the WiFi channel.

I read somewhere that this might be a WPA2-PSK problem, but why now why not since I connected router? Should I switch to WME, WPA, WPA2 or something like that?

I can provide more info if someone out there wants to help me. I appreciate your time!

Comment: What router? Is this only 2.4GHz? What channels did you try? What affect did that have? What's the WiFi environment look like around you? Does it work better when you're closer to the router?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Its Zyxel VMG1312, it is only 2,4, i was automatically on 11 i tried also channel 1. I will try 6.. Enviroment is not that bad there are only 2 or 3 networks with low signal strong coming from neighbours. I dont think it works better as I said my father was pretty close to the router, no walls between and had the same. Like I said it was all good for me too since yesterday. Dont know what happend. I dont think changing channel had some affect on my issue. Its still pretty same. I should have (and i had first weeks) speed around 1000 KB/sec. Now its 300, 500 - 600 then 900 again.

Comment: My gut instinct would be a problem with the router, possibly overheating or crashing. It could also be some new source of WiFi interference, but you would think that changing channels would help with that. Check the position of the router. Is there a source of interference near it? Is it getting good ventilation? Is it aimed sensibly and not hidden behind anything?

Comment: @zx485: Sure. Some time it comes naturally. :)